# R package for fixed-effect logistic regression

Tags: r, logistic, panel-data, clogit

I'm looking for an `R` package for estimating the coefficients of logit models with individual fixed-effect (individual intercept) using Chamberlain's 1980 estimator. It is often known as Chamberlain's fixed-effect logit estimator.

It's a classic estimator when dealing with binary outcome panel data (at least in econometrics), but I just don't find anything related to it in the CRAN.

Any clue?

Comment: Here is another try: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/discrete-choice-panel-models-in-r/13417

Comment: I'm dealing with the same situation, did you find a solution/package/code?

Answer (score 15):

Conditional logistic regression (I assume that this is what you refered to when talking about Chamberlain's estimator) is available through `clogit()` in the [survival](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/index.html) package. I also found this page which contains R code to estimate [conditional logit parameters](http://course.wilkes.edu/Merrill/stories/storyReader%2424). The [survey](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survey/index.html) package also includes a lot of wrapper function for GLM and Survival model in the case of complex sampling, but I didn't look at.

Try also to look at `logit.mixed` in the [Zelig](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Zelig/index.html) package, or directly use the [lme4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) package which provide methods for mixed-effects models with binomial link (see `lmer` or `glmer`).

Did you take a look at [Econometrics in R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Farnsworth-EconometricsInR.pdf), from Grant V. Farnsworth? It seems to provide a gentle overview of applied econometrics in R (with which I am not familiar).

Comment: Actually, "conditional logit" is a very ambiguous term. It some contexts (mainly when dealing with panel data), it is equivalent to Chamberlain's estimator, but it is very unfrequent. Most of the times, it refers to a cross-sectional model where the outcome variable can take more than 2 values. All your proposals actually refers to packages that consider this last possibility. The same with mixed-logit: it is not a fixed-effect logit. I've already taken a look at Farnsworth's overview, but it is not exhaustive enough to speak about this estimator. Anyway, thank you for your answer !

Comment: "Conditional logit" does *not* refer to having more than two outcome levels. Some functions might extend it to that situation, but that is not the point.

Comment: Yup, but the conditional logit model can (as I said) take more than 2 values, which differentiates it easily from Chamberlain's model, just like the fact that Chamberlain is designed specifically for panel data. This is thus a relevant information ; precise description of the usual conditional logit isn't (and the description of both would take more than 600 chars).

Answer (score 3):

You can run the Chamberlains model using `glmer`. It is basically a RE model but with more variables:

```
glmer(y~X + Z + (1|subject), data, model=binomial("probit"))
```

- X are the variables you consider explain your fixed effect model (a simple case it is the mean of Z)
- Z are your exogenous variables
- Subject is the variable where the heterogeneity comes from

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think that would restrict heterogeneity to be orthogonal to X and Z while the requested estimator allows for it.

Comment: No is ramdon effects. It is not chamberlain model which si fixed effects

Answer (score 1):

The `mclogit` package seems to implement conditional logit of the Chamberlain variant.