# Robust fitting of discrete choice model in R

Tags: r, regression, multinomial-distribution, discrete-data, glmnet

I'd be really grateful for recommendations of a robust package for fitting discrete choice models to a large amount ($n$ in the millions and $p$ in 2000 range) of data. I want a smoothed model that can deal with multi-colinear dependent variables and matrix inversion issues sensibly - like [glmnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html). I'm happy to bootstrap samples, which may be the only way to deal with big data in R.

I've tried using the [mlogit](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/index.html) package and it falls apart with more than a few hundred predictors, producing errors to do with matrix inversion.

My alternative is to use the [glmnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html) package for binary regression and then use transforms to approximate the discrete choice model using something called Begg and Gray's approximation.

This data is not multinomial, in the traditional sense. It is discrete-choice, that is the classes themselves change from observation to observation -- possibly also the number of classes. Each of the classes has a set of predictors which are measured on the same scale and are class specific -- cf. [Discrete Choice Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_choice). I wrote to the maintainer of `glmnet`, Trevor Hastie,  who says there is no mapping to discrete choice models in their package.

Another name for discrete-choice is conditional logit, with the correct parameterization. I found the package [pglm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pglm/index.html), but it is also lacking in robustness. There's reference, [Discrete choice panel models in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10141/) to [lme4](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/index.html) also, but I have found no examples of the conditional logit with it.

Answer (score 3):

I know that you have asked for an R package, and I totally understand your desire (as I use R for almost everything). But you should really check out [PythonBiogeme](http://biogeme.epfl.ch) for this level of problem.

Answer (score 0):

glmnet (in the package of the same name) can handle multinomial outcomes if you pass it the argument family="multinomial". The glmnet help also has more information about how it fits multinomial models and how to do grouped lasso penalization.

Comment: The data is not multinomial in the usual sense. There cases in the training set are such that the number and labels of the classes vary from examples to example. Also the covariates have a special structure. I altered the description of the problem above.