# Logistic regression with panel data

Tags: r, logistic, python, panel-data

I am looking for a package/library to run logistic regression on panel data. I already did some research and most of the sources suggest Stata, however, I would like to use R or Python, as I am using one of these for data preparation. I have found [this](https://github.com/nicolashennetier/pyeconometrics), but this is not a well know package as far as I know. Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: `pglm` package in R. You also run `glm` with `family = “binomial” and include your entity variable as a factor and correct the standard errors with the `sandwich` package

Comment: @paqmo The coefficients will be the same in case of using both of the packages and only the standard errors will be different? If so, could you please show some reference so I can read on the subject?

Comment: I should correct myself -- it's a bit more complicated to do a fixed-effect logistic regression, e.g. (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146434/why-pglm-fails-for-within-model)). But there's the `bife` package that does fixed-effects for panel data with binary outcomes.

Comment: In the end I am using a random-effects model so `pglm` is perfectly fine (or `lme4`). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can model longitudinal data within a Generalized Linear Mixed Model (GLMM) framework, if you're looking to implement logistic regressions. One commonly used R package is [`lme4`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/lme4.pdf), you can use the `glmer()` function.

Comment: Note that glmer implements random, rather than fixed effects.  If you're attempting inference and want to control for all cross-sectional heterogeneity, `glmer` won't get you there.  You'd need some implementation of the conditional logit model.

Comment: I had thought that it could include both? Perhaps `clogistic()` within `Epi` could be useful.